# Attribute Error in Django model Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In My Django Project, there are two apps: Login and Company

The **error that am receiving** in this is

```py
AttributeError: module 'login.models' has no attribute 'Country'
```

*Company App* > models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from login import models as LM

class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    full_name            = models.CharField(max_length=255, 
                                            unique = True)

    country              = models.ForeignKey(LM.Country, 
                                            on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                                            null=True, 
                                            blank=False)

    state                = models.ForeignKey(LM.State, 
                                            on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                                            null=True, 
                                            blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

*Login App* > models.py

```py
class Country(models.Model):
    """List of Country"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique= True, default='None')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique= True, primary_key=True, default ='NA')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.code)

class State(models.Model):
    """List fo State"""
    region = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True, primary_key=True, default='None')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, default ='NA')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region
```

Here is test to check that weather is login is getting imported or not

```py
def test_import():
    try:
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        importlib.find_loader('LM.Country')
        found = True
    except ImportError:
        found = False
    print(found)
```

Answer is received stands to be True

```
python3 manage.py shell
>>> test_import()
True
```

Now on other stackoverflow blogs i checked i thought it could be of `Circlular Import`
But i have already fixed that still am getting this error?

Thanks in Advance
Regards

Comment: Can u try :  ```country = models.ForeignKey(LM.Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, default ='NA')```.  in `State`

Comment: Here is the result````state                = models.ForeignKey(LM.Country,```` ```AttributeError: module 'login.models' has no attribute 'Country'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to see any issue here technically. Maybe Django doesn't support this alias way of mentioning model as Foreign Key which I have never tried this way.

But I would suggest to use string format for adding Foreign Key of other model as below.

```
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True)
    # In following line, as I mention model name in string which django understands
    country = models.ForeignKey('login.Country', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                                null=True,blank=False)
```

Another way is simple import but it might be a problem in case of circular depedencies. So I don't recommend to use that.

I hope you get the answer out of it.